# How to create an TextField with input history?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to create a TextField is explained very well in a [tutorial](https://www.jetpackcompose.net/textfield-in-jetpack-compose). But I am wondering how to store and retrieve the entered strings in a persistant way, that survives application termination and restart (something like a Bash history).

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe storing submitted entries in database and loading them when application starts?

Comment: @Hamed I am looking for something simpler. Bash does not use a database either.

Comment: Saving to a file is the simplest, I think

Comment: You probably want to use this. That's the recommended way to store data that doesn't belong in a database on Android
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give you a very briefly answer

You need

1. a viewmodel class
2. a repository class
3. a database (room database is ideal)
4. an entity data class
5. a dao class

You should find more info about room database from jetpack libraries.
Of course are uncounted ways to implement this feature but it is in general the following way recommended.

- You capture from your view the query string, may on submit.
- In viewmodel you implement a method captureSearchQuery(query: String)
- Also in viewmodel you implement a method for example retrieveSearchHistory() : Flow<List>
- The repository class is your single source of true, is the layer between the data layer and the view layer, you implement also this two methods you need, captureSearchQuery and retrieveSearchHistory. In repository class you can may transform your data, for example is a good practice to have a separate data model for the data you display on the view from your room entity. There you can do this transformation for exmaple.
- Now you have setup your room database you can insert and get the data you need.

The data should go this way:

View -> Viewmodel -> Repository -> Room database

View <- Viewmodel <- Repository <- Room database

The layer should never communicate otherway, (clean architecture) for example:
View -> Room database.

The above is my simplest explanation, I hope I help you

Comment: Sounds like much work for a simple list of strings.

Comment: Unfortunately you should use best practices, this way of implementation is extendable. For example may you want implement a new functionality, you want save this data in a server. You can just add functionality without problems.